# Access enum data type from Jquery function

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2, enums

enum Data type is in c# code file as below :

***C# Code :***

```
[Serializable]
[ComVisible(true)]
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6
}
```

I need to accsess above enum type from below mentioned js function.How could I achieve that?

***JS File:*** I need to cast `for loop` variable using enum type.

```
function updateGroupLessonHiddenFields() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        var name = (('<% DayOfWeek%>')i).ToString();
        var key = name.ToLower();
    }
}
```

***ascx file** I can Access that like below:*

```
<%
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        var name = ((DayOfWeek)i).ToString();
        var key = name.ToLower();
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the `javascript` loop variable in c# code. The **loop of javascript will be executed after server end execution is finished and sent to client**, how javascript loop variable i could be used in c# code then?

You can define two string variables to assign names / values of enumeration to javascript.

*Code Behind*

```
public static string names = string.Join(",", Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek)));
public static string values = string.Join(",", Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)));
```

*Javascript*

```
function updateGroupLessonHiddenFields() {         
  var names = '<%= names  %>';
  var key = '<%= values  %>'     
  nameArray = names.split(',');
  valuesArray = values.split(',');
}
```

Comment: may be you have misunderstood my scenario. I need to access c# enum from js function.I edited my post also.In other words I need to cast for loop value using enum. Plz check that.

Comment: The loop of javacript will be executed after server end execution is finished and sent to client, how javascript loop variable i could be used in c# code then?

Comment: I just need enum data type for cast the js function 'for loop' variable value ? In html file I can do that. Plz check updated post.So how can I do that thing in js File ?